# Need help patching a 1.5.0.1 Magento website (1533 & 5344)

Tags: security, patches, magento-1.5

I have scoured all the related "how to apply the security patch" questions already posted and have not been successful. 
The website in question is on hostgator.com and I have access to the cpanel.

I have uploaded the patches to the root folder and now I'm trying to execute the command to run the patch files.

These are the two files I have uploaded to the root folder.
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.10.1.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-20-41.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-5390_CE_1.5.1.0_v1-2015-03-03-09-44-37.sh

This is where I am stuck. I have no idea where to access the command line to run the .sh files. Any help would be greatly appreciated since I am a graphic artist and not a programmer. 
Many thanks,
Brian

Comment: Do you have ssh access? See http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access

Answer (score 1):

To use the magento patch you need to

1) ssh into your magento root folder on your server then run

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.10.1.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-20-41.sh
```

To gain ssh access for hostgator.com see [How Do I Get and Use SSH Access?](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access)

2) Copy your magento files to your local computer and then apply the patch and re upload (if you run a windows os take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/120045/how-to-execute-sh-file-on-windows.

*Please note: that it's never a good idea to run any type of changes on a live server without testing first.*

Comment: Thanks R.S. I'll give it a shot. Though I have no idea how to test the patch first. I have made backups of the site using the cpanel as well as Magento admin panel. Besides that, I have no idea what else I should do.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have managed to login to SSH by using Putty.
You have to enter into putty this commands:

cd yourwebsiteroot

Press enter.

bash patchname.sh

Advanced manual on how to apply magento patch can be found here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html

Comment: Many thanks Vwaida, I'm questioning my host provider about getting ssh access now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to gain SSH access then you could clone all the site files (excluding the `var/` and `media/catalog/product/` folders) to another machine where you *do* have shell access.

You can apply the patches there and then re-upload the changed files to your server.

Comment: Many Thanks STW. I've got SSH access now, but I'm now downloading the entire server so I can test it locally. Though I'll have to cross that bridge once I get to it. R.S. Recommended that I do that so that's what I'm doing. :)

Comment: Since you have ssh you could look into using `rsync`; it's a really handy tool for making sure that file permissions, etc all get preserved

Comment: Ok, I'm breaking down and paying to have it installed. It was a bit too advanced for my tech level. Many thanks to everyone who responded to my post!